# Create graphs similar to Pew Research site

Tags: jquery, css, d3.js, highcharts, flot

Data Visualizations bring data to life.

Here a simple line graph is transformed into something beautiful:
http://www.pewresearch.org/data-trend/media-and-technology/device-ownership/

How did Pew Research make this graph? Is there a technology with some sort of API or plugins available that I could learn? What are some options or places to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That chart is built with [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/). Its an easy to use api for charting based on jQuery. However if you really want to make a great chart, I recommend learning the [d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) api.

view source line 413

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var markerOptions = {
    enabled: true,
    states: {
        hover: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
}

var options = {
    chart: {
        inverted: false,
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Percent of American adults 18+ who own each device'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { 
            text: ''
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            marker: markerOptions
        },
        area: {
            marker: markerOptions
        }
    }
}

Highcharts.visualize($('table').eq(0), options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Deciding on which solution to use often depends on the flexibility you need in your graphs. I would recommend FLOT because it is quick and easy to learn while providing a large number of graph options. This should help you get started http://www.flotcharts.org/

Good Luck!